# Use Apache drill as schema conversion tool

Tags: teradata, hadoop2, apache-drill

I am working on migrating teradata DBs to any open source DB(which DB is under discussion). I came across Apache Drill engine. My question is can we use drill to load data from teradata? If yes, can we use it as a schema conversion tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory yes it can load data from Teradata, since Teradata has a JDBC driver you can configure Teradata as a source. For an example of how to configure a JDBC data source in Drill see the [docs here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/).

Drill has a [CTAS statement](https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/). I know it can be used to write parquet, CSV, and json files, but I'm not sure what other data sources it supports.

To get more information about what Drill can do, and to request features, please get in touch with the Drill team on the [user list](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/).

Comment: Hi. Do you know if we could use drill as a schema converison tool? Like while migrating from teradata to amazon redshift, loading data from teradata using drill and pushing it to redshift, without any hassle. Can we use drill in such a way?

Comment: Currently I don't think so. Right now Drill could only read the data from Teradata if you've configured a jdbc storage plugin and write the data to file using a ctas statement like this. `create table dfs.dumped_table as select * from teradata.mytable` . Note this assumes you've correctly configured a storage plugin for Teradata and named it **teradata*. Send a mail to the drill user list, about the feature you'd like. They'll listen to your suggestion and might add it before the next release.

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks for the inputs.!